# How to create a matrix from combination in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

| V1 | V2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 0.211752 |
| C | A | 0.134699 |
| C | B | -0.210903 |
| D | A | 0.349337 |
| D | B | 0.614440 |
| D | C | -0.220699 |
| E | A | 0.442222 |
| E | B | 0.154271 |
| E | C | 0.240214 |
| E | D | 0.371422 |
| F | A | 0.459264 |
| F | B | -0.057128 |
| F | C | -0.144021 |
| F | D | 0.126519 |
| F | E | 0.477894 |

V1 has no A

And I need to make a matrix that would look like

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.000000 | 0.211752 | 0.134699 | 0.349337 | 0.442222 | 0.459264 |
| B | 0.211752 | 1.000000 | -0.210903 | 0.614440 | 0.154271 | -0.057128 |
| C | 0.134699 | -0.210903 | 1.00000 | -0.220699 | 0.240214 | -0.144021 |
| D | 0.349337 | 0.614440 | -0.220699 | 1.00000 | 0.371422 | 0.126519 |
| E | 0.442222 | 0.154271 | 0.240214 | 0.371422 | 1.000000 | 0.477894 |
| F | 0.459264 | -0.057128 | -0.144021 | 0.126519 | 0.477894 | 1.000000 |

I tried running it like the answer to the question below but I couldn't

[How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 2):

We reshape it to 'wide' with `xtabs`, then update the diagonal

```
out <- xtabs(Value ~ V1 + V2, df1)
out1 <- out + t(out)
diag(out1) <- 1
```

-output

```
out1
#   V2
#V1          A         B         C         D         E
#  B  1.000000  0.134699  0.349337  0.442222  0.459264
#  C  0.134699  1.000000  0.614440  0.154271 -0.057128
#  D  0.349337  0.614440  1.000000  0.240214 -0.144021
#  E  0.442222  0.154271  0.240214  1.000000  0.126519
#  F  0.459264 -0.057128 -0.144021  0.126519  1.000000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), V2 = c("A", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Value = c(0.211752, 
0.134699, -0.210903, 0.349337, 0.61444, -0.220699, 0.442222, 
0.154271, 0.240214, 0.371422, 0.459264, -0.057128, -0.144021, 
0.126519, 0.477894)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: `xtabs` makes things so simple! +1!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `igraph` option

```
`diag<-`(as_adjacency_matrix(
  graph_from_data_frame(df[c(2, 1, 3)], directed = FALSE),
  attr = "Value"
), 1)
```

which gives

```
         A         B         C         D        E         F
A 1.000000  0.211752  0.134699  0.349337 0.442222  0.459264
B 0.211752  1.000000 -0.210903  0.614440 0.154271 -0.057128
C 0.134699 -0.210903  1.000000 -0.220699 0.240214 -0.144021
D 0.349337  0.614440 -0.220699  1.000000 0.371422  0.126519
E 0.442222  0.154271  0.240214  0.371422 1.000000  0.477894
F 0.459264 -0.057128 -0.144021  0.126519 0.477894  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` library you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(V1 = unique(c(V1, V2)), V2 = unique(c(V1, V2))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V1, values_from = Value) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames('V2') %>%
  as.matrix() -> mat

diag(mat) <- 1
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- mat[upper.tri(mat)]

mat
#          A         B         C         D        E         F
#A  1.000000  0.211752  0.134699  0.349337 0.442222  0.459264
#B  0.211752  1.000000 -0.210903  0.614440 0.154271 -0.057128
#C  0.134699 -0.220699  1.000000 -0.220699 0.240214 -0.144021
#D -0.210903  0.442222  0.371422  1.000000 0.371422  0.126519
#E  0.349337  0.154271  0.459264 -0.144021 1.000000  0.477894
#F  0.614440  0.240214 -0.057128  0.126519 0.477894  1.000000
```